# Right most set bit O(log N)

Tags: algorithms, bit-manipulation

I tried to do the problem [Find first set bit](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/find-first-set-bit-1587115620/1/?track=DSASP-BitMagic&batchId=154#) in Geeks for Geeks, and this is the code I used.

```
public static int getFirstSetBitPos(int n){
    int counter = 0;
    while (n > 0){
        if ((n&1) == 1){
            return counter + 1;
        }
        n >>= 1;
        counter ++;
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

The problem asks to solve it in a time complexity of O(logN), and my code is O(N). When I looked at the [editorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/position-of-rightmost-set-bit/), it had this solution.

```
// Java Code for Position of rightmost set bit
class GFG {

    public static int getFirstSetBitPos(int n)
    {
        return (int)((Math.log10(n & -n)) / Math.log10(2)) + 1;
    }

    // Drive code
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n = 12;
        System.out.println(getFirstSetBitPos(n));
    }
}
// This code is contributed by Arnav Kr. Mandal
```

I don't understand this `return (int)((Math.log10(n & -n)) / Math.log10(2)) + 1;` I would appreciate if someone could explain.

I am new to programming and an aspiring competitive programmer.

Comment: Your code seems to me O(logN), whats the problem exactly?

Comment: @SerialLazer: Assuming n is an N bit number, the code is O(log n) = O(n).

Comment: @natnav: "Competitive programming" doesn't pay the bill, and doesn't get you a job. And Mr. Arnav Kr. Mandal would be on my "do not hire" list for writing this abysmal code. Try it for n = 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 etc. and count how many results are correct.

Comment: (@gnasher729: check the capitalisation of the last letter in your comment.)

Comment: (`an aspiring competitive programmer` might want to know/mention [`int Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros​(int i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#numberOfTrailingZeros(int)).)

Comment: (Bonus question: why does the GeeksforGeeks problem choose to ask for the *least* significant bit set, as opposed to *most*?)

Comment: (See also: [Right most set bit O(log N) \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64945370/3789665).)

Comment: greybeard: Because there is a very simple, straightforward, fast and non-geeky solution for both problems, but for the most significant the geeky solution doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions about programming are off-topic, however there are a few computer science questions hidden in here: what `n & -n` does, and how floating point is represented.

The `n & -n` operation isolates the rightmost bit of a word in two's complement arithmetic. This is a very useful operation to know about.

Consider, for example, the following 8-bit word:

```
10010000
```

You can find the two's complement of this by taking the logical not of all the bits:

```
01101111
```

And then adding 1:

```
01110000
```

If you then take the logical and of this with the original word, you get:

```
00010000
```

This is the rightmost set bit of the original word. Please try a few examples for yourself to understand how this operation works.

Once you understand that, the rest is simply calculating base-2 logarithm of this number, essentially finding the highest/leftmost set bit, using an unnecessarily complicated method:

$$\log_2 x = \frac{\log_{10} x}{\log_{10} 2}$$

Quite apart from the fact that this is going to raise a floating point exception if you pass it zero (because what's $\log 0$?), and quite apart from the fact that the computational complexity of `Math.log10` is not specified in the Java standard, floating-point numbers are stored in scientific notation in base-2 internally. The number $128.0$, for example, is stored as $1.0 \times 2^7$. So this is just an overly-complex way of extracting the exponent field of a floating-point number:

```
public static int getFirstSetBitPos(int n)
{
    return (int)Math.getExponent((float)(n & -n)) + 1;
}
```

The idea that you were probably supposed to have, however, is to use some kind of binary search. For a 32-bit integer, for example, you can tell if there is a set bit in the lowest-order 16 bits using a logical and with an appropriate mask:

```
(n & 0xFFFF) == 0
```

If there is a bit set in this range, then the answer to your question, the "find first set" of a number, is between 0 and 15, otherwise it's between 16 and 31. Either way, you have halved the search space. Turning this into an algorithm is left as an exercise.

Comment: Just saying: The assumption that calculating log10(x) where x is an n-bit number can be done in constant time independent of n is quite laughable.

Comment: @Pesudonym Thank you for the detailed explanation! It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I used @Pseudonym and @greybeard suggestions and came up with this solution.

```
public static int getFirstSetBitPos(int n){
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    if (n%2 == 1) return 1;
    return Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros((int) ((n & -n)+1) & n) + 1;
}
```

Comment: Why should numberOfTrailingZeros take time $O(log N)$? Also since Integer is a fixed-length type in java, technically any reasonable algorithm will have complexity $O(1)$.